# own symbol not found cabal test

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm try to add some test to a little project in Haskell. (I'm using a cabal sandbox on Mac OS)

Everything is fine (the Haskell code compile and run perfectly in `cabal repl`.
But when I try to build the test, it compiles fine, but crashes at link time, claiming that it can't find some symbols
which are from my package.

It seems that it's not trying to link with my own module library, even though I added the dependency in the cabal test suite configuration. If I didn't it could compile, did It ?

So is it a (cabal ) configuration problem or something more major ?

Comment: It is hard to say without actual code, but I guess you forgot to add module to cabal file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you Cabal file has a `library`, `executable`, `test-suite` layout. Then you must list the relevant modules in the `library` section of your Cabal file under `exposed-modules` or `other-modules`. In any case, *all* the modules of your package must be listed in the Cabal file.

Comment: You mean in the library/exposed-modules section ? My module is there, as well as in the test suite/build-depends section

Comment: I've edited my answer to make clear that all modules must be listed in the Cabal file, not only the exposed ones.

Comment: Ok. I had a *hidden* submodule which I added to the `other-modules` section and it works. Basically I have a main module which reexport a submodule. I thought this submodule would be linked automatically as the main one depends on it.